# How can I delete a button upon click (Angular)?

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have a button component styled to look like a pill (so it can be tab-focusable for accessibility) that I plan to reuse to display keywords that a user is searching for. I want to be able to delete the "button"/keyword upon clicking the X icon. I have it set so that if a "keyword" is an empty string, the button won't display, and I tried setting the click event to change the keyword to an empty string, but even that isn't working (and it's not the ideal solution anyway). Here's what I have so far:

**HTML:**

```
<button *ngIf="keyword" onClick="clear()">
    {{keyword}}
    <i class="icon" aria-label="clear"></i>
</button>
```

(The X icon is added via CSS.)

**TS:**

```
export class keywordComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() keyword?: string = '';

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  clear() {
    this.keyword = '';
  }
}
```

I know that the onClick is bound to the button, not just the icon right now, but I thought it might be because this.keyword wouldn't target correctly if I had it bound to the icon instead. Ideally, I'd like the button completely deleted, rather than just hidden. Forgive me if the question shows my ignorance; I'm new to this!

Comment: You have an `@Input` binding for `keyword`, Try to notify the parent (from where the keyword comes) Something like this: `@Output() clearKeyword = new EventEmitter();` Inside `clear`  method `this.clearKeyword.emit()`

Comment: @robert Thanks. I've added ` @Output() clearKeyword = new EventEmitter();` and `clear() {this.clearKeyword.emit();}` to the class, but it's not working. Is it because the keyword input is being given by the user? In other words, <keywordComponent keyword="keyword"></keywordComponent>?

Comment: Add a handler something like:   `<keywordComponent keyword="keyword" (clearKeyword)="keyword = ''"></keywordComponent>`

Comment: You should use `(click)` instead of `onClick()`, that is the angular way

Comment: Oh my gosh, @Andres2142 . That was actually all it needed. Sigh. Thank you!

Comment: @BonnieHanks, glad I helped you. You should take a look at this https://angular.io/guide/event-binding

Answer (score 1):

Basically I assume that keywords are stored in an array

```
keywords = ['apple', 'google', 'oracle'];
```

Then displayed with:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let keyword of keywords">
  <app-keyword (clearKeyword)="onClearKeyword($event)" [keyword]="keyword"></app-keyword>
</ng-container>
```

Once `clearKeyword` is triggered this method will try to find the keyword and remove it from the `keywords` array:

```
  onClearKeyword(keyw: string): void {
    console.log('clear keyword:', keyw);

    const index = this.keywords.indexOf(keyw);
    if (index !== -1) {
      this.keywords.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
```

A more complete [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x6jq9g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fkeyword%2Fkeyword.component.html)